# How to center multiple inline-block elements with CSS?

Tags: css

I want to horizontally center two (or possibly more) inline-block elements inside a container block element. It should look like this:

```
--------------------------
|      _____   _____      |
|     |     | |     |     |
|     | foo | | bar |     |
|     |_____| |_____|     |
|_________________________|
```

However, with my broken code, it is currently looking like this:

```
--------------------------
| _____   ____            |
||     | |     |          |
|| foo | | bar |          |
||_____| |_____|          |
|_________________________|
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
 <a>foo</a>
 <a>bar</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div a {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 1em;
 margin: 1em;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
```

The reason why the two anchors have to be inline-block and not just plain inline is because I don't want the anchor's padding and margin to overlap.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Simply set `text-align: center;` on the div container.

Comment: That was simple. I keep on forgetting that `text-align` applies to non-text elements too.

Comment: Should be noted that if you were using `float: left;` before, you'll have to make sure to delete that line and use `display: inline-block;` instead.

Comment: This doesn't work if the `foo` and `bar` elements aren't the same width. Unfortunately. Also, things are getting weird for me when adding `margein-left` and `margin-right` values to add a space between the two elements.

Answer (score 15):

Set `text-align: center;` on the parent element.

Answer (score 8):

have you tried the following?

```
div{
   text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear ...

```
<div style="display: inline-block; text-align: center"> 
  ....
</div>
```

doesn't work with elements of different widths, but

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
<div style="display: inline-block;">
 ....
</div>
</div>
```

does

Answer (score 0):

I used `text-align: "center"` in the parent container, and that centered the ULs on the page, but it also centered the text in the ULs (not desired). So I added a `text-align: "left"` to the `<ul>` so that the text was next to the `list-style`.

Answer (score -1):

You can also do

```css
.div {
    display: inline-block center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

to make the inline block center horizontally!