# How to align links in a navbar not made with a list

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

I am trying to figure out how to align my links to be in the center of the nav bar unlike how they are now up top. I have attached what I have done so far but I am unable to figure out how to align the links to be in the middle. I have attached what I have done below. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

I have tried different content and text align as well as position but to no avail. However I am still only learning and may not have tried everything

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="navbar">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
            <a href="home.html">Home</a>
            <a href="#design">Design</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Photo 
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#phportrait">Portrait</a>
            <a href="#phland">Landscape</a>
            <a href="#phstreet">Street</a>
            <a href="#phproduct">Product</a>
        </div>
        </div>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
        </div>
    </header>
```

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Navbar */

header {
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: futura-pt, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #939393;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 4px;  
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px; 
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #939393;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 35px 35px;
  background-color: inherit; 
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover , .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  color: white;
  transition: background-color 200ms ease-out;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #3E3E3E;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center multiple inline-block elements with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748654/how-to-center-multiple-inline-block-elements-with-css)

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/andrwrbnsn/ag389x4c/13/

If you use flexbox for the navbar `display: flex` you can set `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` that will tell the browser to fill the space on the left and fill the space on the right which will center them. Then set the logo to position absolute so that it doesn't make the buttons off center.

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

Your `navbar` can easily centered using flex property on its parent i.e `header` element. And, you need to set background color of the `header` instead of `navbar`. Consider editing as follows:

```css
header {
/*     align-content: center; */
/*     text-align: center; */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: futura-pt, sans-serif;
}
```